# Upload Alexa Slot Types via API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there anyway of uploading **[Custom Slot Types](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/defining-the-voice-interface#custom-slot-types)** values via an API, so that you do not need to type them in manually using the new **Alexa Skill Builder** interface (if you have many of them):

[image]

I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is to get the model via SMAPI first, edit the json file with your new values and update it via SMAPI again.

```
ask api get-model -s "enter your skill id here" --stage development -l en-US > model.json
```

in the model.json file you can see the slots definition. Change it (with a script or manually) and update the model again

Reference to both commands:

- https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#update-model-subcommand
- https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#update-model-subcommand

Answer (score 0):

It seems not (after searching). There is a feature request logged here with Amazon:

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/9640/api-to-upload-intent-schema-and-sample-utterances.html#answer-77902

Answer (score 0):

As other answers suggest, you can use the SMAPI.

Alternatively, you can select the "code editor" tab on the left and drag/drop or copy/paste your schema json code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this via the SMAPI API/CLI. Take a look at https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html for a full detail - it allows for full model editing via JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In the left bar bellow the "Intents" and "Slot" is the option "JSON Editor". There you can write a JSON for the new intents you want to add.

Example without slot type

```
    {
      "name":"YesIntent",
      "samples":[
          "Yes",
          "Yeah",
          "I do",
          "I am"
      ]
    }
```

Example with slot type

```
    {
      "name":"NumberIntent",
      "slots":[
          {
            "name":"number",
            "type":"AMAZON.NUMBER"
          }
      ],
      "samples":[
          "{number} is my number",
          "{number}",
          "my number is {number}"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/williamwdu/Alexa-Custom-Slot-Generator

I wrote this to convert csv/excel to JSON format so you can paste it into code editor.

Let me know if you have any question.

There is no README for the code coz I have no time these days